# PyTest Case 1: Convert following UnitTest Code into PyTest:

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

How to convert following unitest code into a pytest code

```
class ModelTests(TestCase):
def test_create_user_with_email_successful(self):
    """Test creating a new user with an email is successful"""
    email = "test@londonappdev.com"
    password = "Password123"
    user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)

    self.assertEqual(user.email, email)
    self.assertTrue(user.check_password(password))

def test_new_user_email_normalized(self):
    """Normalize Email"""
    email = "teast@AIOWoev.com"
    password = "Password123"
    user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)
    self.assertEqual(user.email, email.lower())

def test_new_user_invalid_email(self):
    """Creating user with no email fails"""
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        get_user_model().objects.create_user(None, "test123")
```

Query:

- I have written following tests into a pytest but has issue with
  test_new_user_invalid_email, how to correct it?
- As I am new in wrting pytest, so is the
  test_create_user_with_email_successful and
  test_new_user_email_normalized written correctly?

---

```
def test_create_user_with_email_successful(client) -> None:
    email = "test@londonappdev.com"
    password = "Password123"
    user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email=email, 
           password=password)    
    assert user.email == email
    assert user.check_password(password)

def test_new_user_email_normalized(self):
    """Normalize Email"""
    email = "teast@AIOWoev.com"
    password = "Password123"
    user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email=email,                                              
           password=password)
    assert user.email == email.lower()


def test_new_user_invalid_email(self):
 """Creating user with no email fails"""
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as e:
        get_user_model().objects.create_user(None, "test123")
```

Answer (score 2):

looks pretty solid to me! you probably don't need the `as e` in the pytest.raises unless you'd like to assert something about the exception

By the way, there are a few pip packages that can help you do this automatically.

- https://github.com/dannysepler/pytestify (disclosure: I wrote this one)
- https://github.com/pytest-dev/unittest2pytest